# Error with Nested Model Edit page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm tying to perform an edit action on one of my nested models. I keep getting the following error "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class"

I don't know what's going on. Any help?

**Routes**

```
  resources :users, :except => [ :create, :new ] do
     resources :store do
       get "inbox", :on => :collection
       get "openedmessages", :on => :collection
     end
  end
```

**Store Actions**

```
  def edit
    @store = current_user.store.id
  end

  def create
    @store = current_user.store.new(params[:store])
  end

  def update
    @stores = current_user.store.id
    if @stores.update_attributes
      flash[:success] = "Store has been updated"
      render 'edit'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

**View for Edit Action in Store**

```
<ul class="storedashboard_header">
    <li><%= link_to "Manage Gear", user_store_index_path(current_user) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Store Appearance", edit_user_store_path(current_user, @store) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Announcements", '#' %></li>
</ul>
    <%= render "users/userdashboard_header" %>
    <%= render "store/storemenu" %>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
        <%= msg %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div>
        <%= simple_form_for @stores, :html => {:multipart => true, :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
            </br>
            <div style="float: left;">
            <%= f.input :storename %>
            <%= f.input :storeimage %>
            <%= f.input :storelogo %>
            <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-large', style: 'margin-left: 40px;'  %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

**UPDATED**

Changed my Controller to the following:

```
  def edit
    @store = Store.find(current_user.store.id)
  end

  def create
    @store = current_user.store.new(params[:store])
  end

  def update
    @store = Store.find(current_user.store.id)
    if @store.update_attributes(params[:store])
      flash[:success] = "Store has been updated"
      render 'edit'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

**New Error after Update**

undefined method `store_path' for #<#:0x007fec93b97238>

**FINAL FIX**

Needed to fix the view...

```
    <%= simple_form_for [current_user, @store], :html => {:multipart => true, :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question properly:

@store needs to be an object for the model Store instead of just the id.

something like:
@store = Store.find(current_user.store.id) will return the object

Comment: I made your suggested changes and now I'm getting a new error, I updated my question above. undefined method `store_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fec93b93b10>:0x007fec93b97238>